# Elements of Fréchet on a regular are closed

Tags: set-theory

Define the Fréchet filter for a **regular** cardinal $\kappa$ in the following way:

> $\mathcal{F}(\kappa) = \{X \subseteq \kappa \mid |\kappa - X| < \kappa\}$.

I am trying to show that if $X \in \mathcal{F}(\kappa)$, then X is (1) unbounded and (2) closed in $\kappa$.

I have shown (1) but I am struggling with (2) and would appreciate help.

For reference

> If $\kappa$ is a limit ordinal, a subset $X \subseteq \kappa$ is closed in $\kappa$ if for any limit ordinal $\alpha \in \kappa$ holds: if $\alpha \cap X$ is unbounded in $\alpha$ (or equivalently $\sup\alpha \cap X = \alpha$), then $\alpha \in X$.

Comment: Why would this be true? Isn’t e.g., $\omega_1\setminus\{\omega\}$ in $\mathcal F(\omega_1)$ but not closed in $\omega_1$?

Comment: Also, shouldn’t it be $X\subseteq \kappa$ in the definition of $\mathcal F(\kappa)$?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen yes, $X \subseteq \kappa$ indeed, that was a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(2) is false. If $\kappa$ is any uncountable regular cardinal, just let $X = \kappa\setminus \{\alpha\}$ where $\alpha < \kappa$ is a limit ordinal. Then clearly $X\in \mathcal F(\kappa)$ and $X\cap \alpha=\alpha$ is unbounded in $\alpha$ and $\alpha\notin X,$ so $X$ is not closed.

Comment: Hm, thank you! Then there is a mistake in my notes.